# WheelView not found in Android

Tags: java, android, mobile

I downloaded a project from GitHub. When i tried to check its source its gives WheelView error.. WheelView is not importing in it..

```
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

    final WheelView month = (WheelView) findViewById(R.id.month);
    final WheelView year = (WheelView) findViewById(R.id.year);
    final WheelView day = (WheelView) findViewById(R.id.day);

    OnWheelChangedListener listener = new OnWheelChangedListener() {
        public void onChanged(WheelView wheel, int oldValue, int newValue) {
            updateDays(year, month, day);
        }
```

WheelView is not importing, i don't know how to import the WheelView and from Which API in this project?
**This is the link below from where i get the project** 
          https://github.com/abodehq/Hijri-Calendar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i myself got the answer android wheel view is available in google code here is the link

https://code.google.com/p/android-wheel/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2Fwheel%2Fsrc%2Fkankan

Answer (score 1):

There is no `WheelView` in the Android SDK. You will need to check with the author of the project to see where they are getting `WheelView`. Perhaps it is from [this project](https://github.com/LukeDeighton/WheelView).

Comment: This is the link where I get this project https://github.com/abodehq/Hijri-Calendar

Comment: @RanaZubair: In `project.properties`, it is connecting to an Android library project located at `../wheel`. Contact the author and ask what `WheelView` the project uses, or find another project, or rummage through the project's source code and try to find a `WheelView` implementation that matches what the project is trying to use.